# How to wait for firebase data fetch finishes and get values not a promise in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have data in firebase data that looks like the following:

[image]

The code for getting customers data:

```
getCustomersOnQeueu = async () => {
        let customers = this.customersRef.orderByChild("ticket").once('value')
        return customers
      }
```

Code for rendering data:

```
renderCustomers = () => {
        let customersViews = []
         this.getCustomersOnQeueu().then((customers) => {
           let customersTickets = customers.val()
           console.log(customersTickets)
           let sortedKeys = Object.keys(customersTickets).sort(function(a, b){
             return customersTickets[b].ticket - customersTickets[a].ticket
           })
           console.log(sortedKeys)
           for(i=0; i<sortedKeys.length; i++) {
             let key = sortedKeys[i]
             console.log(customersTickets[key]["customer"])
             customersViews.push(<View>
               <Text>{customersTickets[key["customer"]}</Text>
             </View>)
           }
         })
       return (<View>
         <Text>Available Customers: </Text>
         {customersViews}
         </View>)
      }

  render() {
   return (
    <View>
       {this.renderCustomers()}
    </View>
)
}
```

Now after data being fetched and sorted I can see the following in console:

[image]

I have a problem that this line of code is never executed:

```
customersViews.push(<View>
               <Text>{customersTickets[key["customer"]}</Text>
             </View>)
```

I am guessing that it might be because **customersViews** array is initialized after rendering is done and not before, how can I wait for data fetching and sorting to finish then render the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are attempting to get your firebase response you're not actually waiting for it.  The code below does not wait for it to be executed.

```
getCustomersOnQeueu = async () => {
        let customers = this.customersRef.orderByChild("ticket").once('value')
        return customers
      }
```

To WAIT for it to be executed use AWAIT:

```
getCustomersOnQeueu = async () => {
        let customers = await this.customersRef.orderByChild("ticket").once('value')
        return customers
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

setting state via `this.setState()` always rerenders a component. If you want to rerender a vraible's latest value, put it in the state. Putting customerViews in state and updating it via `this.setState()` might solve your problem here.

Comment: Yes, but I still need for firebase data fetch to complete so I can know when to update views.

Comment: `this.getCustomersOnQeueu().then()` this then is executed after data is fetched. You don't have to worry about completing the fetch.

Comment: whenever `then()` will be called, the state would update and hence a rerender would take place. You don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Rerendering the view will make rendering on infinite loop, since I am calling `this.renderCustomers` inside `render()` each time calling `this.setState()` will make infinite loop.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what you are trying to render. a list of names?

It seems that your line you are talking about is not working because customersTickets.push cant push react element to the array.

You can even try it in your developer console

let array = []
arr.push(test)

and the result is "Uncaught SyntaxError"